# Show that $\int_{E} \vert f_{k} − f \vert dm \to 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

> **Problem:** Let $f_k$ be a sequence of non-negative measurable functions such that
>   $f_k \to f$ a.e on $E,\; f \in L(E)$ and $\int_{E} f_{k}dm \to\int_{E} f dm$. Show that $\int_{E} \vert f_{k} − f \vert dm \to 0.$
>
> **What I know:**
>   I cant use the Scheffe's Lemma because I don't know $f_{k}$ are integrable or bounded. So I can't use the $g_{k}=\vert f_{k}-f\vert\leq f_{k}+f$ and consequently DCT.

I need just a hint, not the whole solution.

Comment: $f_k$ must be integrable for large enough $k$. Use Fatou's lemma on $f_k + f - \lvert f_k - f\rvert$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I used but it did not work. Actually, at this condition, I have to use $\int \vert f_k \vert \to \int \vert f\vert $ which is incorrect.

Comment: \begin{align}
2\int_E f\,dm &= \int_E \liminf g_k\,dm \\&\leqslant \liminf \int_E g_k\, dm \\
&= \liminf \Biggl(\int_E f_k\,dm + \int_E f\,dm - \int_E \lvert f_k - f\rvert\,dm\Biggr) \\
&= 2\int_E f\,dm - \limsup \int_E \lvert f_k - f\rvert\,dm\,.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fatou's lemma,
\begin{align*}
\int 2f = \int \lim_{k\to\infty} \left(f_k+f - \lvert f_k-f\rvert\right)
&\leq \liminf_{k\to\infty} \int\left(f_k+f - \lvert f_k-f\rvert\right)\\
&\leq \int 2f - \limsup_{k\to\infty} \int\lvert f_k-f\rvert
\end{align*}
Thus, 
$$
0\leq\limsup_{k\to\infty} \int\lvert f_k-f\rvert \leq \int 2f - \int 2f = 0
$$
Which proves the result.

Answer (score 1):

For large enough $k$, $f_{k}$ is integrable. Using the reverse Fatou's Lemma (which requires precisely this condition on $f_{k}$), we have

$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{E} |f_{k} - f|dm \leq \lim_{k \to \infty}\sup \int_{E}|f_{k} - f|dm \leq \int_{E} \lim_{k \to \infty}\sup |f_{k} - f|dm = 0$.